# Spring PagedListHolder get all records

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create different options for a list view in a spring mvc3 controller where the user will be able to view list paginated in different records, e.g. 10, 25, 50 or all records. For this I'm retrieving my records using Hibernate and pass the result in a PagedListHolder. However I cannot find any documentation on how to set the pagination of the holder so to retrieve all records. One option is to give the PageSize to the count of objects. Is there something else I can do? I thought maybe set the value of the pagesize to 0 or some other value which will give all the records.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Why you want to fetch all records if you are using pagination?

Comment: so that the user will be able to view all records at once

Comment: Then whats the use of pagination?

Comment: write another method to fetch all the records -,-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bit clumsy, but can you set `PagedListHolder#setPageSize()` to the size of the source set?

Comment: Yes, that is what i finished up doing. Thanks for the answer anyway :D